# SiteMapNodes not showing after upgrade from Unity to autofac

Tags: owin, autofac, sitemapnode

We had a development house upgrade our site to use Autofac instead of Unity and now our sitemap is empty - we no longer have our menu items nor do we have our breadcrumb trail. From debugging all I can say with certainty is that our sitemapNodes are empty (Only the root shows up) - running the old and new side by side everything happens in extenral code so I have no idea where it's going wrong. We use a custom implementation of the SiteMapNode to identify our menu items like below

```
 [AuthorizeRights(SystemRights.MyRights)]
        [MyCustomMvcSiteMapNode(LocalizedTitleKey = "MyObject_IndexTitle", ParentKey = "MyObject", Key = "MyObjectIndex", ShowInBreadCrumbOnly = true)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = _myObjectLogic.GetMyObjects();
            var viewModel = new MyObjectsViewModel(list);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

In the old version the code just finds the pages and lines them up in the menu, but in the new code nothing.

I've searched ad nauseum and found countless pages that tell me things like "You need to install these Nuget Packages" or "If you're using OWIN you need this code at startup" but none of it worked.

Can anyone tell me what we are missing?

Comment: Much as I empathize with the frustration, **there's not enough here to go on to help you**. There's a lot of context you have that you're not providing us with, from whether there are any errors (anything in logs?) to whether there were any other differences _at all_ - Unity to Autofac is a step, sure, but that's going to affect your app startup code, your dependency registrations, etc. It's a lot. You will likely need to create a very tiny repro on your system - one page, one node in the site map, original Unity code - then do the upgrade on the tiny repro and see what goes wrong.

Comment: Related: [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TravisIllig Nothing in the logs. The dev house also updated our startup code to use the new dependency injection method (like the aforementioned "code at startup"). I'm going to try your suggestion of creating a small project and upgrading it to see if that sheds any light on the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I've managed to create a miniature web app that recreates the problem (There are actually three versions - a Unity version, a non-DI version, which is basically the unity version with all Unity packages and dependency injection stripped out, and an Autofac version, which is the  non-DI version with dependency injection added in the form of Autofac. The former three verions both display the menu on the left and the latter reproduces the error. I think there's too much code to share it in snippets though, so is there any way I can get you to look at the projects as a whole?